# Cognito login with facebook using Fb SDK

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Here’s the response I get using the Facebook’s SDK [through this plugin](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4):

```
{
    status: “connected”,
    authResponse: {
        session_key: true,
        accessToken: “<long string>“,
        expiresIn: 5183979,
        sig: “...“,
        secret: “...“,
        userID: “634565435”
    }
}
```

The goal is to implement [User Pool Sign-in Through Facebook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-social-idp.html) using the accessToken and not Cognito’s [/authorize](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html) endpoint.

I wasn’t able to find the proper API to accomplish this.

The reason I’m not going for in-app browser is because there, the session is localized, meaning the user would need to input credentials every time, also, it’s [not supported by google auth anymore](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html).